# Building high-performance HTTP compliant upload server with Boost Asio or extending Nginx?

Tags: c++, architecture, nginx, boost-asio, software-design

I'd like to hear your guys opinion on architecture decision.

I'm building high-performance upload server. The purpose of server(s), in simple terms, is to receive huge amount of files from clients and save them on NAS.

Requirements are:

- Files will be uploaded via HTTP POSTs in "multipart/form-data" encoding.
- Each file will be at least few megabytes long.
- Clients are browsers on computers and mobile clients.
- Because at least 50% of clients will be mobile clients I expect these TCP/IP sessions to be pretty long.
- It should not be affected by [Slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris) attacks.
- Target platform is Linux CentOS 6.2.
- As server receives files it saves some info to database, performs authentication and etc.

My current approach is to implement everything (http parsing and etc) myself using [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). I like it because I have greater control on what happens with data. I'm thinking about writing it to file directly from socket using memory mapped files.

Would you say it might be easier to implement it as extension to [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) ? Is Nginx a viable option given the requirements listed above?

Comment: What did you go with in the end?

Comment: @JackTucktcale Scala with akka-streams :)